# datetime.date and datetime.time manipulations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a date and a time column. So basically I want to perform the following manipulations:

```
 #converting queue time(TULSA time) to IST
    for r in range(df.shape[0]):
        queue_date = df.loc[r,'queue date']
        queue_time = df.loc[r,'queue time']
        if queue_date<'2022-03-13':
            ist_time = abs(queue_time + '11:30:00')
        elif queue_date>'2022-03-13':
            ist_time = abs(queue_time + '10:30:00')
        elif queue_date=='2022-03-13':
            if queue_time>='02:00:00':
                ist_time  = abs(queue_time + '10:30:00')
            else:
                ist_time = abs(queue_time + '11:30:00')
```

this piece of code gives the following error :
**TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'**

I tried multiple ways like (mentioned below) but it became lengthy and chaotic.

```
if queue_date<pd.to_datetime('2022-03-13').date():
            ist_time = abs(queue_time + timedelta(hours=11,minutes=30,seconds=0))
        elif queue_date>pd.to_datetime('2022-03-13').date():
            ist_time = abs(queue_time + timedelta(hours=10,minutes=30,seconds=0))
        elif queue_date==pd.to_datetime('2022-03-13').date():
            if queue_time>=pd.to_datetime('02:00:00').time():
                ist_time  = abs(queue_time + timedelta(hours=10,minutes=30,seconds=0))
            else:
                ist_time = abs(queue_time + timedelta(hours=11,minutes=30,seconds=0))
```

The above piece of code gave the error : **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'**

Is there a quick crisp way to do the above manipulations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with timezones it is strongly advised to use the built-in timezone features provided by Python.
So, if you want to get the current time in Tulsa (which I believe is US/Central time) and convert it to Indian Standard Time, you would use the following:

```
import datetime, pytz
# create a datetime for the current time with timezone Tulsa
now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('US/Central'))
# convert to Indian Standard Time
now_ist = now.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
```

That way you don't have to worry about daylight savings time and changes in the time offsets throughout the years.

So for your concrete problem, you will want to interpret the times you have as Tulsa time and create a Tulsa timezone aware datetime (i.e. `tz_localize` it to `US/Central`).

Then you convert the Tulsa time to Indian time by means of `tz_convert` to `Asia/Kolkata`.

```py
# create a dataframe with a string column 'date' containing increasing dates and string column 'time' containing a fixed time
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2022-03-10', periods=10, freq='D').astype(str),  
                   'time': ['09:00:00']*10})

# create a datetime column by combining the date and time columns in central timezone
df['datetime_tulsa'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', utc=False).dt.tz_localize('US/Central')

# convert the tulsa time to indian standard time
df['datetime_ist'] = df['datetime_tulsa'].dt.tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')

df
```

Will give you this:
[image]

As you can see, the difference in time changes on `2022-03-13` as Tulsa goes from Standard Time to Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: thanks for the excellent explaination :) But I don't want the current Tulsa time. I actually have log files which have at what time the query came in. And that time is in Tulsa time. I want to convert and manipulate them.

Comment: What the code above does is: 1. Interpret a given date and time as Tulsa time (`tz_localize`) and 2. convert the Tulsa time to Kolkatta time (`tz_convert`). If not this, maybe you can explain a bit more what it is you are trying to achieve.